# Плагин FancyBox for WordPress для самописного шаблона

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка, css

Есть шаблон WP самописный и стандартный, когда применяю плагин FancyBox for WordPress в стандартной теме, картинки при нажатии увеличиваются, а в самописном - просто нажимаю и открывается в пустом окне картинка, то же самое и без плагина... Не могу понять, какой кусок кода мне нужен к CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самописном библиотеки скриптов все подключены? Гляньте вот тут, возможно вы что-то пропустили при подключении. По шагово сравните. 
[Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/howto)

Comment: спасибо)но я уже решил проблему поставил другой плаг..)хотя ошибка крылась в тех библиотеках)

Answer (score 0):

Вам, скорее всего, нужно посмотреть, какой класс стоит у картинок в рабочем шаблоне, и прописать его в свой.

Comment: не выходит...